# Check if an attribute exists in Objectify polimorphic queries

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

i've a base class `A` that has `X`, `Y` and `Z` subtypes.

I need to query only a subset of subtypes of `A`, like only `X`, or `Y` and `Z` subtypes.

To do this, as the Objectify loader `.type()` method doesn't accept more than one type, i add a

`q.filter("^i in", types);`

to my query, where `^i` is an attribute added by Objectify to `A` (base) class and it's used to handle polimorphic queries and `types` contains the `X`, `Y`, `Z` class names. It works perfectly: i can get entities of desired subtypes.

Now assume thay my `Z` subclass has a `status` attribute (which is not an attribute of `A` class). When i try to filter for both `^i` and `status` attributes together, i always get empty result.

For example, i want get all entities of both `A` subtypes `Y` and `Z`, but only the `Z` entities having the `status` attribute equals to `"active"`.
I build my query as the following:

```
ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(A.class)
    .filter("^i in", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Y", "Z"})
    .filter("status", "active")
    .list();
```

This returns an empty list. If i remove the `status` filter, it returns both `X` and `Z` entities as expected. If the query if only filtered by `Z` type, the `status` filter works well.

As i need both `Y` and `Z` entities, i need a way to filter the `status` attribute as *status doesn't exists or equals to "active"*: first clause for the types that are not `Z`, the second one for thoose are.

Have you any suggestion to do this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a custom index on ^i and status?

Comment: No, i've no control on ^i attribute (it's managed by Objectify internally) but i've an index on status

Comment: May depends because i've this index @Index(IfNotNull.class) on status attribute?

Comment: With @Index annotation i have the same result. I really need an "exist" query operator...

Comment: Although you cannot add an `@Index` annotation to `^i` (I believe it's already indexed), you can try a custom index allowing you to query `^i AND status` with this in your **datastore-indexes.xml** `<datastore-index kind="A"><property name="^i" direction="asc"/><property name="id" direction="asc"/></datastore-index>`

Comment: tx802 has the right idea. I'm surprised that you don't get the line generated into the datastore-indexes-auto.xml when you run this in your dev environment.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try. My datastore-indexes-auto.xml is empty.

Comment: I created from scratch the datastore-indexes.xml with this content: `<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
 <datastore-index kind="A" ancestor="true">
  <property name="^i" direction="asc" />
  <property name="status" direction="asc" />
 </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>`
Nothing changed

Comment: This [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Restrictions_on_queries) says that if an entity (X, Y in my case) has not a property (status, which is on Z) that appears on query filter, it's excluded from result.
I think this is my case... or i'm going wrong?